# sequence of orthogonal matrices in $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, matrices, reference-request, compactness

I have to check whether any sequence of orthogonal matrices in $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ has a convergent subsequence?

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Is there any general method to deal with topological properties of subsets of $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$, defined w.r.t. their algebraic properties - e.g. whether the set of matrices with real traces is compact in $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$?! Any text references will also be appreciated.

Comment: For $n=2$ you can write explicitly the matrices and use that $\mathbb{R}/2\pi \mathbb{Z}$ is compact. Any sequence of matrices whose rows are of unit norm has a convergent sequence, because the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact.

Comment: As for a general method: it might help to consider $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

The set of orthogonal matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, usually denoted by $O(2,\mathbb{R})$. is closed and bounded. Since $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is basically $\mathbb{R}^4$, this proves that $O(2,\mathbb{R})$ is compact. And, in a compact set, every sequence has a convergent subsequence.